# How to use Rails .build to create a user with a stripe subscription

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, stripe-payments

I'm using Rails + Devise along with Stripe for billing. I'm working to create a controller method that creates a user with a subscription at the same time but am running into errors. My controller method:

```
def signup_w_cc
    @user = User.new(:email => params[:user][:email]
    @user.subscriptions.build(:stripe_card_token => params[:stripe_card_token],
                                              :plan_id => 1,
                                              :quantity => 1)
    @user.save
end
```

This is failing, when I do @user.save, the subscription model is not getting the required user_id field. Am I using build incorrectly? The idea is not to create the user and then the subscription as they both need to commit or rollback at the same time.

**user.rb**

```
  has_many :subscriptions
```

**subscription.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

thx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your subscription object won't have an user_id because the user is not persisted yet. There is no id available.

To fix, try to change the order to save user at first. Then `@user.subscription` will have an user_id attached.

```
@user = User.new(:email => params[:user][:email]
@user.save # Save and get id at first.
@user.subscriptions.build(:stripe_card_token => params[:stripe_card_token],
                                          :plan_id => 1,
                                          :quantity => 1)
```

Comment: This is the problem. I need them to either save at the same time or not. The problem with this answer if if the subscription fails, now we have a user created without a subscription.

Comment: @AnApprentice, I understand your concern but without an user who can subscribe? You can not use `transaction` either as payment is external service. My suggestion is to keep them as they may intend to pay but failed due to external reasons. You can send them emails to help if necessary. But if you really don't want them you can run a backend job to remove those failed periodically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you want this kind of awareness out of your relations you'll need to add `inverse_of` options to them:

```
User

has_many :subscriptions, inverse_of: :user


Subscription

belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :subscriptions
```

For more on the `inverse_of` option, search this page for the term `inverse_of` until you get down to the `has_many` code: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods

Does that help?